# TypeError: x is not a function Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add a date into the name of an exported pdf from Google sheets, and it keeps telling me:
TypeError: date is not a function
from the bottom line of this code:

```
var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "YYMMdd");

var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E7').getValue();

var pdfName = value +"_SGConformance_"+ date();
```

Is it an easy fix?

Comment: variable is `date` - and you put `date()`. There is no need to put parentheses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

As [Sergey said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67564013/typeerror-x-is-not-a-function-google-sheets#comment119421650_67564013), you don't need to add parentheses to `date`. You should remove them.

Parentheses can be used to call a function, but `date` is not a function. `date` is a `string`, since it's returned from [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)).

#### Reference:

- [Calling functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#calling_functions)